# SVG clip-path in background-image – Firefox not working

Tags: svg, background-image, clip

ClipPath doesn’t seem to work in Firefox. When the SVG File is embedded as a background-image (first image). Does anybody has a trick or work-around to fix this? I don’t want to embed it as an object or img.

[image: Embedded as background]
[image: Embedded as object]

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
        <circle cx="32" cy="32.2" r="16"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<g style="clip-path: url(#myClip);">
    <line class="sb s_3" x1="11.5" y1="38.4" x2="48.9" y2="20.8"/>
    <line class="sb s_05" x1="13.6" y1="42.7" x2="50.9" y2="25"/>
    <line class="sb s_05" x1="15.1" y1="44.7" x2="52.5" y2="27.1"/>
    <line class="sb s_2" x1="15.6" y1="49" x2="53" y2="31.3"/>
    <line class="sb s_05" x1="9.4" y1="34.2" x2="46.8" y2="16.6"/>
    <line class="sb s_05" x1="7.8" y1="33.1" x2="45.2" y2="15.5"/>
</g>
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me so the issue is in some code you've not shown us.

Comment: Nope. Even the most basic example shown here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath), doesn’t work when embedded as a background-image. Probably a bug in Firefox (latest). Opera, Chrome, Safari and even IE 11 work fine.

Comment: That works for me as a background image too. I'm not sure what mistake you're making if whatever you're doing works in other UAs. Try safe-mode and/or a new profile perhaps.